# How to extract certain text from a controller in Rails into column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out a way to extract specific word from a DB record, so far I've tried the following hopefully it will show and give an idea what I'm after

```
test = Message.where(:msg_id => params[:id])
test.content
=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at diam sapien. Nullam aliquet risus ac ex luctus, eu faucibus leo sodales. Cras tempus volutpat purus at dignissim. Nullam eu tortor in felis pretium venenatis et at sem. Proin malesuada pellentesque massa quis efficitur. Sed a pharetra sem. @John"
```

I'm trying to grab anything that starts with `@` in controller or different symbol (# or %) and  save it under a different value. I've tried

```
content = test.content.pluck.start_with? '@'
Message.user = content
Message.save
```

Something like that but it didn't work. In other words, my `test.content` has that big message and either at the end or at the beginning (preferred at beginning) one would put @john or #john and then message .. like so;

```
#John Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at diam sapien. Nullam aliquet risus ac ex luctus, eu faucibus leo sodales. Cras tempus volutpat purus at dignissim. Nullam eu tortor in felis pretium venenatis et at sem. Proin malesuada pellentesque massa quis efficitur. Sed a pharetra sem.
```

Then my controller would extract `#John` or `#john` or whatever from `test.content` and put it under `test.username`

suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message.user = content
```

First of all this won't work, because Message here is class name
Probably you should use @message or something around it

To extract username you can use regex, or simply text.split(' ').select { |word| word[0] == '@' }

Comment: the `split` stuff works for me but is I'm getting a lot of garbage in my `test.username` ... it looks like this `"---\n- Lorem\n"`, not very clean `Lorem` ... don't need the extra characters. Suggestion?

Comment: nevermind, thanks for your help :) just added `.first` to that line and it cleared stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use regular expressions? For instance for getting the name John in your first content:

```
/@(\w*)/.match(test.conent)[1] # outputs John
```

Use http://rubular.com/ for creating your own regular expression.